# Android Studio - Creating a `custom Progress Bar like `Scanning for Devices`

Tags: android, android-studio, android-custom-view

Does anyone know how to Create a Custom Progress Bar like `Scanning for Devices`. I am currently creating my own app and it has a function with `Searching for Device`, I want to show a `loading` while searching but instead of progress bar or circle progress i want to show like the below image:

[Sample Searching 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXclG.jpg) [Sample Searching 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Obf8.jpg)

Its feels like it is Searching for Device and I want to have it instead of Progress Bar. If Someone know how to create this or Library for this it would be help for me.

I'm not really sure what they called on this but I'm hoping someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a library you can use to accomplish similar effect: [jfabrix101/RadarCustomVIew](https://github.com/jfabrix101/RadarCustomVIew)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this before accepting as a correct answer. Thank you very much!